# Why will my python paths mess up my package import?

Tags: python, import, package, pyautogui, inkscape

I installed pyautogui.
I try to run this program.
`import pyautogui print(pyautogui.size())`
It doesnt work with:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWiN.png)
This is already strange to me as no2.py is not in .venv so why does it try to run it there:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svarv.png)

I had a whole weird construct anyways because I installed Inkscape years ago which changed my default python path apparently. I saw it here. I uninstalled inkscape in between first I got oen, then the other thing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvG3n.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQVWF.png)

The first screenshot is how I even noticed that that is a problem.

So one problem is already solved.

Now I have the situation that by pressing the "play" button I get the error mentioned in the beginning.
when I however type the command it works like a charm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwWQr.png)

See above.See above.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two installations of a python. One in `Inkscape`, which the one you invoke using the cli (try `which python` to see which binary is executed)
That python has the `pyautogui` module installed, which is why when you run it from the command line using `python no2.py`, it works.

However, when you use your IDE's "play button", it has been configured to use the python binary installed in the `.venv` folder (which is why you see in your traceback this `.venv` appearing. It's not the location of your `no2.py` script, but the python environment. And that environment doesn't have the `pyautogui` installed, hence the error you are getting.

To solve this, either use the `Inkscape` python environment, and configure your IDE to use this environment, or install `pyautogui` in the environment in `.venv`

Comment: Thank you. I did however not find where to change the standard interpreter. I was just lucky enough that after deleting the .venv it detected that it pointed to nothing and offered to change back to my default python.

I however already deleted my Inkscape python so it now goes to the installation I want.

I just am a bit confused why my terminal does not launch in the venv i am currently in. Because it doesnt i cannot install extensions in it with the command.

Comment: You should look into "python virtual environment" managers, such as [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) for instance, to manage more cleanly your python environments :)